# Transformation formula for densities of random vectors with different dimensions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^d, Y: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^p $ be two random vectors where $d \neq p$, and $Y=u(X)$ where $u$ is continuously differentiable. Under what conditions on $u$, there's a way to find a local/global mathematical relation between the corresponding densities $f_X \equiv f_X(x), f_Y \equiv f_Y(y)$ of $X, Y$ respectively? For example, if $Du$ is surjective at every point and has a full rank at every point, can we use the implicit function theorem to establish (perhaps locally, but globally would be even better!) a relation between the two densities $f_X \equiv f_X(x), f_Y \equiv f_Y(y)$? Note that, I'm not assuming any forms on the distributions of $X,Y$.

P.S. I understand there's an extensive literature when $d=p,$ but I didn't find anything resonable when $d \neq p$. So if you just direct me to a paper or book, that'd be enough for now, although an answer would be great too.

P.P.S. What'd be the answer(s) to the equivalent questions for complex random vectors?